# Getting html tag into data from API post method

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo2z3.jpg)

using API post method to fetch data into modal. getting tags into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some kind of parser library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser.

Install: `npm i html-react-parser`

```
const parse = require("html-react-parser");

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {parse(yourHtmlResponseString)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

Important:

> Since adjacent elements are parsed as an array, make sure to render them under a parent node:

Also set the default value for the response data you want to render to a string, so the parser can handle it easily, if you haven't done so already.